# Jacobi's Formula for Solutions of $\dot{x}=f(x)$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, jacobian

**Lemma** Let $\phi_t(x)$ denote the solution of $\dot{y}=f(y)$ from initial condition $x$. Then the following identity holds:
$$\det \frac{{\rm d}\phi_t(x)}{{\rm d} x}=e^{\int_0^t \nabla\cdot f(\phi_s(x)){\rm ds}}$$

I have found the above Lemma, without any proof given. It is simply stated that ``it follows from standard ODE techniques''. It seems to be strictly related to Jacobi's formula, however, I did not manage to prove it.

Comment: Sorry, had to edit. Calling the solution and the initial condition $x$ makes it unreadable. Also, is $f \in C^1$?

Comment: Indeed, you are right. We can take $f\in C^\infty$.

Comment: Then we can get the ODE $\partial_t D_x \phi_t(x) = D_x \partial_t \phi_t(x) = Df(\phi_t(x)) D_x \phi_t(x)$ for $t \mapsto D_x\phi_t(x)$. I do not quite know how this solution operator looks, but write it down and then apply the determinant.